# Anonymous class implementing an interface

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, anonymous-class

I have the following interface:

```
public interface MessageFactory<T extends Message> {

    public T create(Session session);
}
```

when I define the class like this, Eclipse gives me the error in the comment below on that line:

```
public abstract class MessageType<T extends Message> implements MessageFactory<T>{

    public static final MessageType<ObjectMessage> PLAYER_REGISTER = new MessageType<ObjectMessage>() {

        @Override
        public ObjectMessage create(Session session) { //Error, remove @Override annotation
            //impl
        }
    };

    private MessageType(){ }
}
```

But if I copy-and-paste the `create` method from the interface into the class as an abstract method, the error goes away:

```
public abstract class MessageType<T extends Message> implements MessageFactory<T>{

    public static final MessageType<ObjectMessage> PLAYER_REGISTER = new MessageType<ObjectMessage>() {

        @Override
        public ObjectMessage create(Session session) {  //Fine
            //impl
        }
    };

    public abstract T create(Session session);

    private MessageType(){ }
}
```

What's wrong with anonymous classes implementing interfaces?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but in the first snippet `abstract class MessageType` should anyway inherit `T create(Session session)` method from implemented interface, didn't it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Not clear. The anonymous class extends the MessageType<T> which in turn implements the interface. Therefore the anonymous class implements the interface.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder __you're not implementing the interface, you're subclassing MessageType__ If we're subclassing a type implementing an interface the subclass will implement the interface too. So we just need to override its methods.I really don't understand the problem in my example.

Comment: @St.Antario: It's true, you're marking `MessageType` as abstract. I can't replicate the error: http://ideone.com/hMBPMX Are you sure this isn't an IDE bug?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Maybe. I use eclipse... thank you anyway.

Comment: @St.Antario I've just also tried to reproduce the problem and both snippets worked well for me. Are you sure that in both cases you import the same `Message` class? Maybe you just erroneously imported another `Message` class in the first snippet - it happens

Comment: @Yura Of course, the class is from JMS-api. It's probably an eclipse bug.

Comment: @St.Antario hmmm, if this bug keeps occuring then probably it's a bug of Eclipse, because it uses it's own Java compiler from JDT Core, which may contain bugs from release to release. In my Eclipse 4.4.1 release with Java 8 I couldn't reproduce this bug

Comment: @Yura I use 4.5.0 and Java7 compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like an IDE bug of some kind; Java's compiler is perfectly happy with it. If I set up that situation and use Oracle's Java8 `javac`, it compiles just fine.

It's fine [here on IDEOne](http://ideone.com/hMBPMX) using non-public classes, or if I create these files and compile them:

`Message.java`:

```
public class Message { }
```

`ObjectMessage.java`:

```
public class ObjectMessage extends Message { }
```

`Session.java`:

```
public class Session { }
```

`MessageFactory.java`:

```
public interface MessageFactory<T extends Message> {

    public T create(Session session);
}
```

`MessageType.java`:

```
public abstract class MessageType<T extends Message> implements MessageFactory<T>{

    public static final MessageType<ObjectMessage> PLAYER_REGISTER = new MessageType<ObjectMessage>() {

        @Override
        public ObjectMessage create(Session session) { //Error, remove @Override annotation
            return null;
        }
    };

    private MessageType(){ }
}
```